# Redirect to another website according to answer - SP Designer 2007

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-list, redirect

I´m quite new in the world of SharePoint. What I´m trying to do in the intranet of the company I work for is the following:

Create a form using a custom list where workers can report whenever an accident happens.

There, they will have the option to give a suggestion to improve it ("Do you have a suggestion for it?" Yes or No question).

If they choose yes, they should be redirected to the another website of the company specific for the suggestions´ program.

Any idea of how to do it using SP Designer 2007 or directly using IE?

I´m sorry if the questions is too basic, I don´t have much experience here.

Thanks,
Lucas